# How to create a link that makes a PUT/POST request to AWS API Gateway to update an item in DynamoDB?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway that has a PUT method to update an item on a DynamoDB table. It is working fine if I use Postman and set the Content-type to application/json and include the JSON as the body. See below:

PUT: https://XXXXXXXXXX/dev/ID

Body:

> {
>       "callerId": "XXXX",
>       "caseNumber": "YYYYY",
>       "count": 1,
>       "handled": true }

My main goal behind this is to be able to send a link to and end user where they can click and it automatically updates the Item in DynamoDB. Any ideas on how to create a link that makes a PUT request to and endpoint and passes JSON content that is going to be used to update the Item?

I have all the information I need I just don't know how to construct the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user clicks a link that you send them, their browser will always issue a GET request for that URL.

Why not also route GET requests for that resource to the same action as what you're currently doing with PUT?